# console.log not working when using @submit directive in vuetify

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

When using the `@submit` directive in Vuetify, `console.log` is not working in my code.  But when I only use `@click` and then call my function it works. Any idea how to make that work?

This code works:

```html
<v-btn color="primary" text @click="submit">I accept</v-btn>
```

HTML in template

```html
<v-btn color="primary" text @submit="submit">I accept</v-btn>
```

Function being called

```js
  methods: {
    submit() {
      console.log.$refs

      // Form validation check
      if (!this.$refs.invoiceform.validate()) {
        console.log("Not good");
      } else {
        console.log("Data ok");
      }
  },
```

Comment: Sorry, badly formatted the question (first post, sorry). The code that is not working is  <v-btn color="primary" text @submit="submit">I accept</v-btn>

Comment: Are you sure `submit` is an event that `v-btn` emits? I know `v-form` emits `submit`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem I believe is that `v-btn` does not have a `@submit` event so you need to put that on the `v-form` element if you are using it. Make sure your button is inside the form element and it is of the type submit.  Use `prevent` on the form submit event to prevent it from causing the browser to try to post your form.

```
<v-form @submit.prevent="submit">
     ...//some inputs
     <v-btn type="submit">I accept</v-btn>
</v-form>
```